# Capture accept revision event in MS Word VSTO add-in

Tags: events, ms-word, vsto, add-in

Is there a way to hook into an event when user accepts a revision on a single word in MS-Word VSTO addin?

Or generaly: Is there some general approach to hook into events initiated by actions of a user in ms-word?